# Settings on ISO and Aperture for Sunset on Canon 600D

Tags: sunset

I will be going to a beach location and there will be opportunities for some good sunsets.

I have a Canon 600D with 2 lenses and wanted to know the range for ISO and aperture settings.

I am doing daily home work with normal sunsets and want some guidance on the range of settings.

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Generally, f8, 1/250 at ISO 100 gives a good exposure for sunset. Ofcourse, this exposure set may vary depending on the light. I prefer to underexpose by about 1/3rd a stop for rich saturated colours.

Comment: How can this possibly be true given that the light at sunsets varies enormously?

Comment: As I added, of course this is bound to change. On a clear day with no clouds, these settings would work. However, not always. This is just a rough starting setting for capturing sunsets. It will definitely vary as per availability or non-availability of light.